# Is there anyway to create related entites within a post request with django rest framwork?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

If I sound confused, it's because I am.
I'm unfamiliar with the django rest framework and I'm attempting to create a relatively simple Recipe-Managing app that allows you to automatically create your shopping list.

**Motivations :**
I know that DRF might not be needed and I could just use django, but the point of this app is to learn how to use the DRF.
The goal is to create a back with DRF and do some fancy shenanigans with a front framework afterward.

**Problem:**
I have a `Recipe` model which contains a `ManyToMany` field to `Ingredient` ***through*** `RecipeIngredient`. And I am a bit confused on how I should approach the `RecipeSerializer`.
So far it looks like that :

```py
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id','name','ingredients','tags','prep_time','cook_time', 'servings', 'instructions')
```

But I feel like whenever I will want to create a Recipe, I'll have to fire a post request to create the `Ingredients` (if they do not exist yet), one to create the `Instructions`, one to create the `Recipe` and one to create the `RecipeIngredients`.

**Question :**
Is there a way to make one request containing the recipe and all sub fields (ingredient, recipeingredient, instruction)  and to create all the entities ?
That would be handled by the `create` function of the `RecipeSerializer` I suppose.

**Model:**

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient,through='RecipeIngredient')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='recipes')
    prep_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cook_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    servings = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Instruction(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='instructions', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, null= False, blank=True)
```

**Serializers:**

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Recipe.objects.all(), many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id','name', 'recipes')

class InstructionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Instruction
        fields = ('id','number','text','recipe')


class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('id','name')

class RecipeIngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = ('id','ingredient','recipe','quantity','unit')


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id','name','ingredients','tags','prep_time','cook_time', 'servings', 'instructions')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializers, You can change the RecipeSerializer as follows

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
    
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('id','name','ingredients','tags','prep_time','cook_time', 'servings', 'instructions')
```